# I have a issue with formatDate in w2ui

Tags: date-formatting, w2ui

Help please .....What's wrong ?

In Linux or Windows, Chrome or Firefox

if in console, I run:

```
w2utils.formatDate('2016-07-12', 'd/m/y');
```

Return **11/7/2016** ( not 12/7/2016 !!!! )

I'm in Argentina ( timezone -3 )
Does it have something to do with it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. My fix was to use momentjs instead.

so instead of this

`w2utils.formatDate('2016-07-12', 'd/m/y');`

try this:

`moment('2016-07-12').format('DD/MM/YYYY');`